# Button in UITableViewCell invisible when swiped outside screen

Tags: uitableview

I made a custom `UITableViewCell` that works fine, except for the fact that when I swipe the cell outside the screen the button becomes invisible:

[image: button invisble after swiping outside top of screen]
.

When I change to another view and change back, the button is visible again:

[image: button visible]
.

The button is still there and can be tapped to call the procedure, but the text seems to become nil.
Any idea why?

The code:

**SettingsViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SettingsViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *settingsTable;
@end
```

**SettingsViewController.m**

```
#import "SettingsViewController.h"
#import "MyCellClass.h"
@interface SettingsViewController ()
@end

@implementation SettingsViewController
{
    NSMutableArray *_tableSectionNames;
    NSMutableArray *_cellGroups;
    NSMutableArray *_cellGroup;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _cellGroups = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    _cellGroup = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    _tableSectionNames = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Login", nil];

    MyCellClass *myCell = [[self settingsTable] dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"myCell"];
    [myCell.textLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Logged in as 1"]];
    [myCell.button setTitle:@"Logout" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [myCell.button addTarget:self action:@selector(userLogout) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [_cellGroup addObject:myCell];
    [_cellGroups addObject:_cellGroup];

    [[self settingsTable] reloadData];
}

#pragma mark - Settings table view

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [_cellGroups[section] count];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [_cellGroups count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return [_cellGroups[indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (_tableSectionNames[section])
    {
        return _tableSectionNames[section];
    } else
    {
        return @"";
    }
}
```

**MyCellClass.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MyCellClass : UITableViewCell
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *button;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *textLabel;
@end
```

**MyCellClass.m**

```
#import "MyCellClass.h"

@implementation MyCellClass

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

@end
```

This is when I see my custom cell with button:

```
<MyCellClass: 0xa7cf1b0; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 55; 320 44); text = 'Logged in as 1'; autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0xa7cf380>>
   | <UITableViewCellScrollView: 0xa7bc3c0; frame = (0 0; 320 44); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0xa7bc650>; layer = <CALayer: 0xa7bc590>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>
   |    | <UITableViewCellContentView: 0xa7cf470; frame = (0 0; 320 44); opaque = NO; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0xa7be530>; layer = <CALayer: 0xa7bbdf0>>
   |    |    | <UIButton: 0xa7bbe20; frame = (217 5; 83 33); opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0xa7bbf10>>
   |    |    | <UILabel: 0xa7bbf40; frame = (15 17; 199 21); text = 'Logged in as 1'; clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xa772f80>>
```

This is when I see the standard UITableViewCell without button after swiping:

```
<MyCellClass: 0xa7cf1b0; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 55; 320 44); text = 'Logged in as 1'; autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0xa7cf380>>
   | <UITableViewCellScrollView: 0xa7bc3c0; frame = (0 0; 320 44); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0xa7bc650>; layer = <CALayer: 0xa7bc590>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>
   |    | <UITableViewCellContentView: 0xa7cf470; frame = (0 0; 320 43.5); opaque = NO; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0xa7be530>; layer = <CALayer: 0xa7bbdf0>>
   |    |    | <UIButton: 0xa7bbe20; frame = (217 5; 83 33); opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0xa7bbf10>>
   |    |    |    | <UIButtonLabel: 0xa897150; frame = (29 6; 54 21); text = 'Logout'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xa896860>>
   |    |    | <UILabel: 0xa7bbf40; frame = (15 17; 199 21); text = 'Logged in as 1'; clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xa772f80>>
   |    | <_UITableViewCellSeparatorView: 0xa88e8b0; frame = (0 43.5; 320 0.5); layer = <CALayer: 0xa8717d0>>
   |    | <_UITableViewCellSeparatorView: 0xa8780b0; frame = (0 0; 320 0.5); layer = <CALayer: 0xa882550>>
```

Comment: Show the code for your table delegate / data source methods

Comment: So what is in `MyCellClass` as the table code doesn't really do anything. (also, when are you creating the `_cell*` arrays - just not shown I guess?)

Comment: Sorry, forgot the cell inits to copy, added to post. Also added the cell class. Btw the button does not disappear, only the text disappears as I can still tap it and the procedure gets called.

Comment: Looks like the wrong implementation (`SFYUITableViewCellLogin`). But, cutting to details, where is the button created, it's frame set, its auto layout/resizing rules specified. Try breaking when the cell is redisplayed and finding out the frame of the button.

Comment: Ok, well, from that code the cell isn't recreated at any point in time so you'll need to debug to find out what happens to the button. I suspected frame change, but you say the button is still there. Is the text still there but a different colour? Any UIAppearance used anywhere. Need to debug.

Comment: Implementation is the right one, forgot to change the name for better readability - edited. The button is created in storyboard. I just figured that when I uncheck "Use Autolayout" in storyboard the button is never visible.

Comment: I noticed that my customized cell becomes a standard cell once it's swiped out. I didn't notice earlier because the only difference was the button. When I change the position of the text label I can see that it's position changes to the label position in the standard cell. The same happens when I call "reloadData" on the UITableView instead of swiping out of screen.

Comment: Implement `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` and in it log `NSLog(@"%@ : \n%@", indexPath, [cell recursiveDescription]);`

Comment: No visible interface declared the selector 'recursiveDescription'. But I did [self.view subviews] and added some of the log to the post. Are these differences of relevance: contentOffset: {0, 0} vs. contentOffset: {0, 97.5} and frame = (0 431; 0 49) vs. frame = (0 480; 0 0) ?

Comment: A frame of `(0 480; 0 0)` has no width or height so isn't very useful. `[(id)cell recursiveDescription]` might work (usually use `po [cell recursiveDescription]` rather than in code)

Comment: Worked in command line, pasted the output in post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason was that i set the @properties of my custom cell as "weak" instead of "strong":

```
@interface MyCustomCell : UITableViewCell
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *buttonRight;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *textLabel;
@end
```

So I changed it to "strong":

```
@interface MyCustomCell : UITableViewCell
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *buttonRight;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *textLabel;
@end
```

Then I saw two texts overlapping each other. The reason for that was that I named the text label `textLabel` which is the same name as the text label in `UITableViewCell`. So I basically filled both text labels with the same text and I noticed only the button to disappear, but actually it was the whole custom cell class that disappeared.

So I changed also the property name and it worked fine:

```
@interface MyCustomCell : UITableViewCell
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *buttonRight;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *labelLeft;
@end
```